# как убрать тег <return> в SOAP ответе?

Tags: java, soap

Делаю SOAP сервер, использую javax.jws. Мой класс (упрощенно) выглядит так:

```
@WebService
public class SOAPService{
    @WebMethod
    public SomeClass myMethod(){
        return new SomeClass("test");
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class SomeClass {
    @XmlElement(name="test")
    Srting test;  

    // гетеры, сетеры
}
```

Все прекрасно выполняется. На запрос

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wp="http:/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wp:myMethod>
      </wp:myMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

получаю ответ

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:wp:myMethod xmlns:ns2="http://">
         <return>
            <test>test</test>
         </return>
      </ns2:wp:myMethod>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

(ну или как то так, вбил тестовый пример от руки, без отладки)

Соответственно вопрос, а как убрать тег `<return>`?. Т.е. я хочу, что бы сразу шло  `<test>`.
Смотрел на анотацию `@WebResult` но она не дает возможность убрать тег, а просто позволяет его переименовать, а мне надо именно убрать его.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503346/how-to-prevent-namespace-wrapper-tags-in-soap-wsdl/38509549#38509549

Comment: Ага, оно. Спасибо